# Is it possible to split an exit block into multiple enter blocks in Anylogic using a set of parameters that can be optimised?

Tags: optimization, simulation, anylogic, discrete-optimization

[image: Simplified model outline]

I want to be able to split activity across a number of sites, but I want that split to be determined by an optimisation experiment so I need a way of splitting activity in the exit and sending it to the respective enter blocks. I'd welcome any advice on how to set up my exit block to do this. I recognise I'll need a variable per option.

I know I can do it with a SelectOut block, but I may need a large number of options and so this doesn't work.

I've added the enter blocks into a collection and I can route agents to a particular enter block,  but the optimisation engine can't use agent level parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Create a function `f_getEnterBlockToUse` that takes as an argument your agent and returns an `Enter` block (select the return type "Other" and then write `Enter` in the code field).

Now, you can write any sophisticated code in there yourself to select which block to be chosen.

In the `Exit` block, you only call the function `f_getEnterBlockToUse(agent).take(agent)`. This will send your agent to your desired enter block

Comment: Thanks Benjamin, I've only just discovered SelectOutputIn and Out which are helpful to my use case.

Comment: True, same thing, I prefer functions :D